# Ec2 1/2 checks passed every 2 or 3 days

Tags: amazon-ec2

I get every 2 or 3 days "Ec2 1/2 checks passed" alarm and my instance is not reachable. I can resolve it just by stopping and starting it again (not by rebooting), basically the problem is in "Instance Status Checks".
My instance type is "t2.micro" and used Amazon Linux AMI.
Any help?

Comment: You're sure it's the *system* status check, not the *instance* status check, that is failing?  It's highly improbable -- perhaps not even possible -- for the system check to fail with the instance check continuing to pass.

Comment: To be precise during 2 weeks, I got 2 times *instance status check* and 3 times *system status check* and in both cases I should stop the instance and start it again. The problem couldn't be solved by rebooting. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: It happens again today and it is *instance status check* and I can just make it working by stopping and starting again.

Comment: Did this problem get rectified? I'm also experiencing same issue.

Comment: No, I upgrade the instance and it gone!

Comment: @Keivan What was your previous plan? What are the options that you upgraded to? We are also facing the same issue, and our website is a WordPress website that is hosted on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server.

Comment: @vimal.roy If I remember it correctly it was `t2.micro`, then based on requirements I had to change it to `t2.large`. But since then it has been change couple of times. Consider upvoting the question, so it reaches more developers!

Answer (score -2):

From [Status Checks for Your Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html):

> **System Status Checks**
>
> Monitor the AWS systems on which your instance runs. These checks detect underlying problems with your instance that require AWS involvement to repair. 
>   The following are examples of problems that can cause system status checks to fail:
>
> - Loss of network connectivity
> - Loss of system power
> - Software issues on the physical host
> - Hardware issues on the physical host that impact network reachability
>
> **Instance Status Checks**
>
> Monitor the software and network configuration of your individual instance.The following are examples of problems that can cause instance status checks to fail:
>
> - Failed system status checks
> - Incorrect networking or startup configuration
> - Exhausted memory
> - Corrupted file system
> - Incompatible kernel

Basically, the **System Status Check** says that something is wrong with the hardware, and the **Instance Status Check** says that something is wrong with the virtual machine (eg kernel problems, networking).

When an instance is *stopped* and then *started* again, it is provisioned on different hardware. This will resolve hardware-related issue. Please note that *rebooting* will *not* re-provision the virtual machine — instead, the operating system simply restarts. That's why a stop/start is more effective than a reboot.

It is quite rare to have the *instance status check* fail after some period of time — it normally has problems at initial startup. This suggests that something is going wrong with your operating system, but that should be corrected by a reboot, which you say isn't sufficient. So, it's a bit of a mystery.

If possible, I would suggest launching a new instance and installing/configuring it as a replacement to the existing instance.